# Media in CSS is not working

Tags: html, css

I am using `@media` queries in my css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px ){ 
    #guarantee{ 
        margin-right: 250px;
    }
} 

@media only screen and (max-width:480px ){
    #guarantee{
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
}
```

When I shrink the browser window the margin width is still the same. It's not overriding 250 pixel as I defined it as default value.

Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Please add your relevant HTML & CSS, ideally in a JSfiddle.net demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net add some code html ,css

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you provided:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:481px){ 
    #guarantee{ 
        margin-right: 250px;
    }
} 

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    #guarantee{
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine - see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmdgtbov/

**UPDATE:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: `@media only screen` is valid, to hide queries from older browsers. See example 9 http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0

Comment: Oops I removed it unintentionally.  `@media only` is correct, however the error is in the `space` between the second query between `@` and `media`. I have replaced the `only`s in each.

Comment: @avenparker see my jsfiddle, it works my end. updated with screenshots